# Does a hive query written in pyspark run against spark or against hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

If I register a hive table in pyspark and then write sql against the table, does the sql hit the underlying hive database every time, or does it run against the data loaded in the spark cluster?
I am running this in a jupyter notebook

```
hive_context = HiveContext(sc) #Initialize Hive
tbl_df = hive_context.table("hive_schema.hive_tbl_name")

tbl_df.registerTempTable("hive_tbl_name");
#Do the below queries run against Hive or against Spark

hive_context.sql("select count(*) from hive_tbl_name".).show();
hive_context.sql("select max(col1) from hive_tbl_name".).show();
```

Comment: What does the history show in YARN?

Comment: I am using jupyter notebook which sits on a remote server, and i have no way of seeing the logs

Comment: Ahh that's similar to Zeppelin Notebook which runs Hive via Spark, unless you have a TEZ connector setup I would assume its spark

Comment: As per my understanding, hive table is nothing just the metadata information for the file. So, if file consist of metadata e.g parquet, it does not seek any information from hive table until and unless we explicitly define to fetch metadata from hive only(parquet have that property). If file does not consist of schema e.g textFile, it fetches metadata from hive itself. So, it is a very subjective question and it depends on type of file system you are using.

Comment: @Perto Zeppelin doesn't talk to HiveServer using the Spark interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the sql hit the underlying hive database every time, or does it run against the data loaded in the spark cluster?

Neither.

- If data is not cached,  query hits the disk every time it is executed. There is no "loaded in the Spark cluster" state.
- Query never hits "underlying hive database every time." since Hive is not a database. Spark reads table information from the Hive metastore. There is no HiveServer execution involved, no matter the context.

Finally PySpark is not relevant at all here. Execution engine is the same, independent of the language bindings.

Comment: I understand hive is not a database. The underlying is stored in hdfs. My question was does the query hit the hdfs every time.